KivyMD - ImportError: cannot import name 'MDApp' from 'kivymd'
Recién instalé kivyMD en la nueva máquina y tengo un problema con el código que figura en la misma página de kivyMD.
El código es el siguiente:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MDLabel(text="Hello, World", halign="center")


MainApp().run()

Para instalar kivyMD, intenté seguir los pasos de codemy.com, en su video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycoKlFV3-iU
La única modificación que hice fue la carpeta del entorno virutal, la cual llamé MDvirt.
EDIT: Cambié el código según la sugerencia de FJSevilla y ya no tengo el otro error, pero ahora me figura otro.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\kivymd\MDvirt\firsproject.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
   File "C:\kivymd\MDvirt\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\label\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from .label import MDIcon, MDLabel  # NOQA F401
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "C:\kivymd\MDvirt\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\label\label.py", line 595, in <module>
     with open(
          ^^^^^
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\kivymd\\MDvirt\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivymd\\uix\\label\\label.kv'

Busqué el archivo en la carpeta indicada y efectivamente no esta. ¿Es un problema de instalación? De ser así, ¿es necesario reinstalar todo o se puede salvar reinstalando sólo una parte?
UPDATE: buscando en otros foros, encontré que puedo crear el archivo y el problema se soluciona. Efectivamente es así, pero ahora me figura que hay otro archivo que no encuentra. ¿Qué recomiendan? ¿Instalo todo de nuevo? O ¿voy creando los archivos necesarios?
Muchas gracias

Dejo acá abajo el error inicial por las dudas.
Y el error que me arroja es:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\kivymd\MDvirt\firsproject.py", line 1, in <module>
    from kivymd import MDApp
ImportError: cannot import name 'MDApp' from 'kivymd' (C:\kivymd\MDvirt\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py)


Estás importando la clase MDApp mal, no es from kivymd import MDApp sino from kivymd.app import MDApp. O has cometido un error al copiar el código o tienen un error en la documentación.

No te puedo creer! Y creí haber visto línea por línea. Igual, ahora que lo cambié me figura otro error. Antes de agregarlo, voy a estar 100% seguro de copiar línea por línea como corresponde.

En cuanto al nuevo error, el archivo que parece faltarte es https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/label/label.kv y no debería faltar en una instalación correcta... ¿Qué versión de Python estás usando en ese VENV?

La versión 3.12.3. Seguí los pasos del video que indiqué arriba. Igual, sólo para crear el VENV. Lo otro es igual a lo que dice la página. Me conviene reinstalralo?

Puedes copiar los archivos que falten de la rama apropiada del repo de Github, pero algo anda mal con esa instalación... Esos archivos definen los widgets propios de kivyMD y no deben faltar, en mi caso en Linux con misma versión de Python y KivyMD no se presenta ese problema. Una cosa, en el video creo instalan kivyMD desde la rama máster de github, yo te recomendaría instalar desde PyPI (pip instal  kivymd), eso instala la última versión estable lanzada y no la versión en desarrollo la cual lógicamente es susceptible de tener bugs o ser inestable, a no ser que tengas una razón para ello.

Buenísimo! Más tarde lo pruebo. Muchas gracias

Lo volví a instalar con ese método y ahora parece funcionar. Muchas gracias
